# Configure JAXB compiler options in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, wizard

I'm trying to generate JAXB classes from a .xsd file.
I figured out that I need JAVA EE version of Eclipse to do that.
If I right click on the .xsd file and choose Generate>JAXB Classes.

I get the same wizard this guy gets in his tutorial video > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOLziP28598&t=2m26s

But the problem is, that if I hit next, the title in the wizard change from "Specify project for the new classes" to "Configure JAXB compiler options", but the form underneath stays the same.

So everytime I click next, the title in the wizard changes, but the form is still showing the project tree form from the first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for using JAXB in eclipse. U have to add a plugin to eclipse.

Download this **org.jvnet.jaxbw.eclipse_1.0.0** plugin  and put it in your eclipse -> plugin directory.(ur indigo eclipse folder) . Restart your eclipse. Then right click on the xsd file -> JAXB 2.0 -> Run XJC.

http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/sample-on-jaxb-using-eclipse/ This link explains the procedure well.

Comment: Are you sure it is not build-in inside java EE versions?
Your solution gives an extra menu item.

Comment: have u followed the steps in that site??

Comment: yes, it is a jar file instead of zip.
But I put the jar file inside my plugins folder and reboot eclipse.
Did also a project clean

Comment: http://www.assembla.com/code/lehmanRepo/subversion/nodes/Libraries/JaxB%20Parser/org.jvnet.jaxbw.eclipse_1.1.zip?rev=431

Comment: Download the zip file from the above link. and extract and put both the folder and jar inside the plugin folder of eclipse.. Restart the eclipse and try

Comment: Thanks TFOOL, that worked perfectly.
The download link on the rocksolutions website was broken.

Comment: @Dreamer: I followed your steps. But I couldn't find the JAXB project in eclipse. I am using eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32 version

Answer (score -1):

Just had this issue, my solution was:
Help>>Install New Software>>Works with:--All Available Sites--

Search for JAXB

Then select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development and install.

After you restart Eclipse you should see the generate option.